# matplotlib.pyplot plotting categories and subcategories as x-axis on one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, minitab

In the program Minitab, there is a way to specify a categorical and sub-categorical type of x-axis for interval plots [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLBPJ.png)

Is there a way to mimic this type of x-tick representation using matplotlib? I tried to look through the documentation as well as stack overflow questions but the closest I could come up with [is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VQci.png) where the higher-level categories are just consecutively repeated. I would like to have it such that, for example, the outermost category p1 would be displayed only once in the center of the first six x-axis ticks instead of repeated six times for each x-axis tick

Comment: Matplotlib provides two levels of ticking "major" and "minor". There is no good interface for 3 levels. Possible hacks are to use a twiny axis for that purpose, or to manually place `text` labels at the respective positions.